# Python - can't see all the attributes of an imported module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a question about dynamic module importing and how `dir/vars/__dict__` behaves with the imported module.

I have the following directory tree:

```
|sv
    |--__init__.py
    |tests
        |----__init__.py
        |some_test
            |----test.py
            |----__init__.py
    |tools
        |----__init__.py
        |SVE
            |----__init__.py
            |prun
                |----__init__.py
                |----prun.py
```

i'm running `prun.py` using this command:

```
python -m sv.tools.SVE.prun.prun
```

in `prun.py`, i have this code(i'll refer to this as the Critical_Code):

```
sys.path.insert(1 ,full_path_to_folder)
curr_test = importlib.import_module("test", "sv.tests." + "some_test")
print dir(curr_test)
```

`full_path_to_folder` points to `ROOT/sv/tests/some_test`

this is how `sv/tests/some_test/test.py` looks like:

```
import getpass
from sv.tools.SVE.svTest.svTest import Test
import sv.tools.SVE.utils.utils as utils
import sv.tools.SVE.utils.remote_operations as remote_operations


class NewClass(Test):
    pass
```

After this long prolog, here is my question:
i'm running prun and i'm importing `test.py` using the import_module and i print it's content using `dir()`, and this is the result:

```
['NewClass', 'Test', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'getpass', 'remote_operations', 'utils']
```

Which is what i expect to see.

But when i remove the first line from the Critical_Code and don't add the path to sv/tests/some_test to PATH this is what dir() prints:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

Which does not contain all the imports inside test.py and the class defined in it.

Why is that? Why dir() shows more when i add to PATH the path to the some_test?
i tried using vars and `__dict__` instead but they all behave the same.